# Use Biztalk training kit on a Virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit laptop with 8 GB RAM. I am trying to get the [Biztalk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14865) training kit() installed on a VM on this machine. I have used Oracle VirtualBox to create a windows 2008 64 bit Virtual machine. I am able to run the "VM\common\BizTalk2010Demo.vhd" (i.e Biztalk Server 2010 Virtual machine) from the Biztalk training kit.

My question is how can I now install all the Training Kit's VM's into the windows 2008 64 bit Virtual machine's Hyper-V?

I would like to work with a virtual machine instead of installing Windows Server 2008 operating system on my machine or installing Biztalk server on my machine. The [install instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14865) are noted down below.

Please note I am a newbie in VM's so I would appreciate any inputs if I am doing something totally wrong.

> In order to use this evaluation package you will need to have
>   Microsoft Hyper-V installed on a physical machine. Hyper-V is
>   available on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2. This
>   virtual machine requires Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2. Details on
>   how to install Hyper-V can be found here. Details of how to setup the
>   VHD are included in the documentation that accompanies the product. In
>   the Setup folder there is an application that will add all the VMs
>   into Hyper-V. The app does this while maintaining only a single copy
>   of the base images. To install, open a command promt with the "Run as
>   Administrator" option and change directory to the setup folder. The
>   import will fail if you do not run the command prompt with this
>   option. Then run the command: importVM.exe full path to base image For
>   example, if the root of the labs is c:\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010
>   Training, then the command would be: importVM.exe "C:\Microsoft
>   BizTalk Server 2010 Training\VM\common\BizTalk2010Demo.vhd"